# Is it possible to have socket.io live update an iframe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, websocket, socket.io

Basically I’d like to have an octane in the middle of a pager linking to a specific website. Let’s say google in this case.

Would it be possible using socket.io to have that iframe update live for everyone? Like if I where to search inside The google Iframe “http://example.com” , Can i make it so that it updates for everyone?

Comment: You could do something like that from your own iframe, but not from a google-controlled iframe.  Your Javascript can't reach into a google-controlled iframe due to cross origin restrictions in the browser.

Comment: is there any alternative/hacky ways to get around this? doesn't have to be with an iframe, basically what i am trying to do is make it so you can wath a youtube video realtime with friends

Comment: It would take some exploration of the youtube embedding to see if they expose cross origin access to video events allow you to synchronize access across multiple clients.  It sounds like something Google would want you to be able to do, but you'd have to explore the specific APIs involved in embedding a youtube video.

Comment: Well hey that’s a start. I’ll look into it. Thank you!

Comment: So what you need is basically someone will browse webpages with iframe, you need to send that URL to other clients their iframe will be updated accordingly but remember, that will be asynchronous depends on their internet speed, some people will see youtube ads, some of them will wait to video to load, etc.

There is a youtube javascript API that allows you to capture events if you need to. So you may try to synchronise play times maybe.